# preventing xml namespaces passing to children

Tags: xml-namespaces

I have a bunch of namespaces in the xsl:stylesheet  element How do I prevent the namespaces from being reflected in the children of the root. Assume i generate something like :

for eg:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:a="aaa" xmlns:b="bbb">
</xsl:stylesheet>

<result xmlns:a="aaa" xmlns:b="bbb">
 <child1> 
  <gchild11></gchild11>
 </child1>
 <child2> </child2>
 <child3> </child3>
</result>
```

now, when I fetch a particular child from the tree, how do I prevent the namespaces from being passed on ?

that is, i should get :

```
 <child3> </child3>
```

and not

```
<child3 xmlns:a="aaa" xmlns:b="bbb"> </child3>
```

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you care? Is it important for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your  declaration:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="a b"
```